# NumPy - reshaping an array to 1-D

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am having problems converting a NumPy array into a 1-D. I looked into ideas I found on SO, but the problem persists.

```
nu = np.reshape(np.dot(prior.T, randn(d)), -1)
print 'nu1', str(nu.shape)
print nu
nu = nu.ravel()
print 'nu2', str(nu.shape)
print nu
nu = nu.flatten()
print 'nu3', str(nu.shape)
print nu
nu = nu.reshape(d)
print 'nu4', str(nu.shape)
print nu
```

The code produces the following output:

```
nu1 (1, 200)
[[-0.0174428  -0.01855013 ... 0.01137508  0.00577147]]
nu2 (1, 200)
[[-0.0174428  -0.01855013 ... 0.01137508  0.00577147]]
nu3 (1, 200)
[[-0.0174428  -0.01855013 ... 0.01137508  0.00577147]]
nu4 (1, 200)
[[-0.0174428  -0.01855013 ... 0.01137508  0.00577147]]
```

What do you think might be the problem? What mistake I am doing?

EDIT: prior is (200,200), d is 200. I want to get 1-D array: [-0.0174428  -0.01855013 ... 0.01137508  0.00577147] of size (200,). d is 200.

EDIT2: Also randn is from numpy.random (from numpy.random import randn)

Comment: What are the dimensions of `prior`? Also, what are you expecting?

Comment: prior is (200,200). I want to get 1-D array: [-0.0174428  -0.01855013 ... 0.01137508  0.00577147]

Comment: Could you add some code for `prior`? Setting it to `np.ones([d,d])` results in the output you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `prior` is most likely a `np.matrix` which is a subclass of `ndarray`. `np.matrix`s are always 2D. So `nu` is a `np.matrix` and is 2D as well.

To make it `1D`, first convert it to a regular `ndarray`:

```
nu = np.asarray(nu)
```

---

For example,

```
In [47]: prior = np.matrix(np.random.random((200,200)))

In [48]: d = 200

In [49]: nu = np.reshape(np.dot(prior.T, randn(d)), -1)

In [50]: type(nu)
Out[50]: numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix

In [51]: nu.shape
Out[51]: (1, 200)

In [52]: nu.ravel().shape
Out[52]: (1, 200)
```

But if you make `nu` an ndarray:

```
In [55]: nu = np.asarray(nu)

In [56]: nu.ravel().shape
Out[56]: (200,)
```

Comment: Nice catch!  I was driving myself crazy trying to think of some weird `dtype=object` explanation but it wasn't happening..

Comment: `np.array` makes a copy of the data by default. Unless that is really what you want, it is better to get a view, either calling `np.asarray` or `np.array(..., copy=False)`.

Comment: @Jaime: Thanks for the improvement.