# Python error: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1, 10) instead

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting this error: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1, 10) instead.

```
filename="UrbanSound8K/car_horn.wav"
audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(filename, res_type='kaiser_fast') 
mfccs_features = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
mfccs_scaled_features = np.mean(mfccs_features.T,axis=0)

print(mfccs_scaled_features)
mfccs_scaled_features=mfccs_scaled_features.reshape(1,-1)
print(mfccs_scaled_features)
print(mfccs_scaled_features.shape)
predicted_label=model.predict(mfccs_scaled_features)
print(predicted_label)
prediction_class = labelencoder.inverse_transform(predicted_label) 
prediction_class
```

Error image:
[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Could you please copy the error and paste it into a code block in the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy - reshaping an array to 1-D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021939/numpy-reshaping-an-array-to-1-d)

Answer (score 2):

1D array and a 2D array with shape (1,10) are two different things. The 2nd one is a 2D array where number of rows happen to be 1.

They are interconvertible.

```
y=np.random.uniform(0,1,size=[1,10]) #Random array of shape (1,10)
y_oned=y.reshape(10) #Reshaping it into a 1D array

print(y_oned.shape)
```

Output

`(10,)` which is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can squeeze the shape of `predicted_label` from (1,10) to (10,) by using `np.squeeze`. Replace your offending line with below code.

```
prediction_class =labelencoder.inverse_transform(np.squeeze(predicted_label))
```